# How are reviewers rated by editors after a peer review proccess?

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

I am aware that some journals ask the editorial board to rate each reviewer, and use these ratings to select reviewers.

So, my question is: how does this rating proccess work? With respect to what are we reviewers rated? How are these ratings used and are they shared between different journals of the same publisher? Is this practice common for all fields? Details are welcome.

I am aware that there are multiple questions, but they are correlated and a comprehensive response can answer all of those questions.

Comment: Some answers can be found in https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31364/after-long-time-without-three-review-invitations-in-two-weeks-coincidence-or?rq=1

Comment: @Mark Thanks, it does seem that some issues are at least partially answered in the quoted question.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably guess how reviewers are rated. Did you provide a good review (as in, read the paper and provide constructive comments)? Did you provide a review on time? Did you write a biased review (a giveaway would be to say the paper's acceptable if and only if the author cites your papers)? If you wrote a good review then you get a high score, otherwise you get a low one. If you get a high score then editors are theoretically more inclined to invite you in the future; the converse is true if you get a low one.

Whether or not ratings are shared between different journals of the same publisher depends on the publisher and the editorial boards of both journals. Obviously, journals can only share reviewers if they have some overlap in scope. There're also technical limitations to linking reviewers. Different journals use different systems, and while it's theoretically possible to link all of them to the same database, it's not always done. Beyond that the editorial boards must also agree. If an editor is relying on his or her personal network, (s)he might be less willing to share. Comparatively, if an editor is using Google Scholar, Web of Science, etc to find reviewers then (s)he might not object.

Comment: I would add that assuming the reports are of decent quality, a referee who never or rarely decline invitation will tend to get an "exponentially" growing number of papers to review.